# Configuring email in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I made fresh installation of Windows Server 2003 and XAMPP. Installed Drupal 7 and the site is functioning properly. However, I am not able to send email. After searching I made the following configuration in php.ini and sendmail.ini.

### Settings in php.ini

```
SMTP = mail.myserver.com
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = myid@myserver.com
```

### Settings in sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=mail.myserver.com
smtp_port=25
auth_username=myid@myserver.com
auth_password=mypassword
```

Note: We are using another machine (our own) for email server. That will be accessed as mail.myserver.com.

Problem:
I tested the service using php mail code and receiving the 'Success message'. But mail not delivered. The log file shows 
    authorization failed (#5.7.0)

but I used double checked my userid and password which is correct. I also changed the code in sendmail.ini
    smtp_server=localhost

I received the error message "Socket Error # 10061Connection refused."

Kindly help to rectify the problem.

regards
Devan

Comment: Is the mailserver accepting connections from outside or only from localhost?

Comment: Mail server accepts connections from outside also. I am not using any SSL in my website.

Comment: Is the mail maybe rejected by the target mailserver? Or maybe in SPAM?

Comment: Thanks. Since the mail server is maintained by another person, I will confirm the same.